# Dumping files based on specific word

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep, sort

I have a file:

```
begin  
path: good  
take this way  
easier path
end  

begin  
path: bad  
You shouldn't go there  
end

begin  
path: good  
Very smooth   
end

begin  
path: bad  
you may face problem  
end
```

Based on path, I have to create a file:

> good.txt

```
begin  
path: good  
take this way
easier path 
end 

begin  
path: good  
Very smooth   
end
```

Is that possible by only using `unix` command like `grep` `awk` `sed` `sort`?

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, assuming the format of the "path" records is exactly as shown, you could use `awk` in *paragraph mode*

```
awk '{print > $3".txt"}' RS= ORS='\n\n' file
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different tools you can use on linux:

- `sh|bash|ksh|csh`- or some other shell
- `awk`
- `perl`
- `python` (depends of it its installed)

Or any combination of the above tools.

Possible solution using `bash` and `sed`, see the notes after on limitations / assumptions:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IN_FILE="$1"   ## Argument: test.txt
OUT_FILE=

# See done for
while read LINE
do
    case $LINE in
        begin)
            OUT_FILE=
            ;;

        path:*)
            OUT_FILE=$(echo "$LINE" | sed 's/^path: \(.*\)/\1/g').txt
            ## TODO: Do a first-seen OUT_FILE check and truncate file.
            echo "begin" >> "$OUT_FILE"   # TODO: Write from buffer instead
            echo "$LINE" >> "$OUT_FILE"
            ;;

        *)
            if [ ! -z "$OUT_FILE" ]
            then
                echo "$LINE" >> "$OUT_FILE"
            else
                ## TODO: Append to a buffer
            fi
           ;;
    esac
done < "$IN_FILE"
```

**NOTE:** *The above code produced the output expected, but I haven't reviewed it to make sure the logic is complete / error free.*

It also has the following limitations and issues:

- Will append to `.txt` files even if they already exist (a uniqueness check can be added on request)
- Assumes that the `begin` precedes `path:..` and it can therefor ignore that line from input and write it out when path is encountered.  It would be possible to create a `BUFFER` variable but I haven't done that at this point.
- It is possibly missing some checks for blank OUT_FILE.

Comment: I have changed my question a bit. Now I would like to create a file at a time. Is that possible by only using unix command like `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `sort`?  

And also it will be great if u provide example by using `bash`. Actually I am trying to solve same problem by using diffrentt tools. I already solved it by using `tcl`. THanKs for Your help.

Comment: OK. I may have gone over board in providing a working example.   But, it does demonstrate the use of case statements available in `bash` for simple pattern matching and `sed` for extracting what you need from a line.  Anything more complicated and I would probably recommend using `awk`.  It should be noted that some tools provide richer features on newer Linux environments over older Linux or Unix environments.  Do you know what version of Linux / Unix you need to learn this for?